# Login page not working angular js

Tags: angularjs, button, input, authentication, angularjs-ng-disabled

I am trying to disable my Login button, when nothing is present in the form fields. I am already using ng-disabled, could any body help why it is not getting disabled.
Find the sample code below: I have checked in previous posts but the code written there is almost the same as that to the format. I am still not able to disable it

```
<b>
        <form role="form" name="form" id="form" ng-submit="loginValidate()">
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="form-group">        
<label>Username &nbsp;</label> <input class="form-text" type="text" ng-model="username" name="username" />                  
</div>                      
<div class="form-group">                        
<label>Password &nbsp;</label> <input class="form-text" type="text" ng-model="password" name="password" />       
</div>                  
<div>
<p>                     
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"                           
ng-click="submitted=true" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Login</button>        
</p>                    
</div>                  
</form>
<b>
```

The form defined here is a simple form, yet i am not able to disable the Login button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you missed to use `"required"` tag in input fields!

try like below once

```
<b>
<form role="form" name="form" id="form" ng-submit="loginValidate()">
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="form-group">        
<label>Username &nbsp;</label> <input class="form-text" type="text" ng-model="username" name="username" required />                  
</div>                      
<div class="form-group">                        
<label>Password &nbsp;</label> <input class="form-text" type="text" ng-model="password" name="password" required />       
</div>                  
<div>
<p>                     
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"                           
ng-click="submitted=true" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Login</button>        
</p>                    
</div>                  
</form>
<b>
```

Comment: Happy to help u! Upvote would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the button disabled even when first time the form is loaded, you can write below code:

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitted=true" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || !username || !password">Login</button>`

Comment: Thank you , I had missed the required button in the input tags.